# How to open sublime text 3 from console with the current folders as project?

Tags: shell, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'd like to open sublime text 3 with the project from the console. The project is the current folder where I enter `'subl'`. For example:

```
cd ./project/test-1

pwd

subl .
```

after the I entered `subl` in the console, sublime text 3 is open and open the `./project/test-1` as the current project. I know it is possible [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz3kElLbEHE) at 4:50.  How?

Comment: I don't understand your question - what exactly are you trying to do? `subl .` will open Sublime with the current folder in the sidebar. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: yes, exactly! Sorry, I know my question needs improvement.

Comment: It's not that the question needs improvement - there **is** no question.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the full path as the argument to `-a`:

```bash
subl -a "$PWD"
# or
subl -a $(pwd)
```

Make sure your version of sublime support the `-a` option:

```
subl --help


Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

Comment: "subl" results "zsh: command not found: subl". Do I need to make a link (ln) to link sublime text to "subl"? I read many tutorials online, but failed to do so.

Comment: You said: "after the I entered `subl` in the console, sublime text 3 is open ...". So I thought you set an alias `subl=sublime`.